# error in indirect file load in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying indirect file load in Informatica.

I put below files in $PmSrcFilesDir (from here the workflow task pick up files)

```
-list.txt
-production_plan_20210906.csv
-production_plan_20210907.csv
```

The list.txt files contains the csv file names only.

I configured below options:

```
Source filetype- Indirect
Source filename- list.txt
Source file directory- $PMSourceFileDir
```

After running the workflow it shows error- as
FR_3000 Error Opening File...No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You can give absolute path in list.txt.

```
/Path/to/file/production_plan_20210906.csv
/Path/to/file/production_plan_20210907.csv
```

You can use command task or shell script to get absolute path and file name.
Pls check session log, which file it cant read - list file or main file. If list file mention $PMSourceFileDir  correctly in param file.
Now, make sure informatica user (user that runs infa server) has read access to those data, list folders and files. Admin can help.